# Where is the login with Stack Exchange option gone?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, login

I have an account on Stack Exchange but when I try to login to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) I do not see the option *Login with Stack Exchange*.

[image: new login screen]

Why is this option now not available?

Comment: There's a new [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263470/make-clear-in-the-logon-screen-you-can-log-in-with-your-se-account) raised after you posted this suggesting to make it more clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's right in front of you:

> [image]

Don't click any of the pretty icons; just fill in your email and password.

Comment: but it is confusing, previously we have a StackExchange icon in login screen. you can see all other sites (literally almost all sites) have got place for placing there icon in login page but StackExchange not ?

Comment: @jophyjob Now that you know how it works, is there still anything confusing about it?

Comment: Well, I agree with @jophy that a title "Stack Exchange" above the text boxes can help prevent future confusion. :)

Comment: Sorry, the user is full aware that there is a login screen, I personally used to click a 'Login With Stackexchange' type oAuth mechanism but now I never see it so I'm logged out of most stackexchange sites and to log in with my secure password in my password manager each time is a hassle