# StackID page needs updated verbiage

Tags: bug, login, stack-exchange-openid

> [image: Image showing how text is no longer in keeping with actual login page]

As you can see in the above screenshot, the SE login pages no longer have a button to log in with the StackExchange OpenID.

The verbiage is out of date, and should be updated. Or a button should be added back. For the sake of lazy I want the button back.

Probably need to mention that folks who are used to logging in with the OpenID can now use their OpenID login info on all sites login boxes.

Comment: as for click the “Log In with Stack Exchange” button goes, Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263470/make-clear-in-the-logon-screen-you-can-log-in-with-your-se-account

Comment: @jcolebrand imgur does not keep images forever, think that only for 6 months after last view or something like that. This means that at some point, your screenshot would disappear. That's why I re-uploaded it to the dedicated account of Stack Exchange (you can do it also, by clicking the Image icon in SE editor, instead of uploading directly to imgur) . Second fix I did was place the screenshot as a quote, so that it will be more clear it's a screenshot. First issue is critical, second is minor.

Comment: Ahhhhh, thanks, I couldn't spot the difference. Thank you.