# Where is my account?

Tags: support

I usually go on stack overflow every day. Every time it automatically logs me in. Suddenly, it does not automatically log in anymore, and when I try to log in NONE of my e-mails work. It always says that there is no account that exists with the email. I tried all of mine (and I have not deleted or added any since I created a stack exchange account). I am not banned; here is my user account page: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3830983/mcmastery
What has happened?

Comment: You apparently have multiple accounts. You might want to [merge them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/168244)

Comment: Contact the team via the *Contact Us* link in the footer of the site. I don't think you have tried the email address that is actually associated with the account, but this is not the channel to suss out if you can remember the email address.

Answer (score 2):

> **TL;DR** - your account is hiding behind the red Google button

Most likely you got confused by the new login page design. In the past, logging in using Stack Exchange OpenID required clicking a button, and only then type email and password.

However since the change, this is what we see:

[image]

Looks like you missed the "Google" button (assuming you created the account using Google in the first place) and instead directly typed your gmail email and password then clicked the blue "Log in".

But indeed, you do not have Stack Exchange OpenID account, hence you fail to login.

I agree it's very misleading and a poor design choice, and there is existing feature request asking to make it clear what is the purpose of the big textboxes and "Log in" button: [Make clear in the logon screen you can log in with your SE account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263470/make-clear-in-the-logon-screen-you-can-log-in-with-your-se-account)

Comment: I think there is some sort of A/B test going on the 'Login' page. But, the [feature-req](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263470/make-clear-in-the-logon-screen-you-can-log-in-with-your-se-account) has not got any attention or 'status-review' tag.

Comment: @Hack why, what do you see? :)

Comment: I don't remember the question but read in the comments about fine tuning 'Login' screen. I will dig more and will update you.

Comment: FWIW, the [tasteslikejava on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3198300/tasteslikejava) was created 1.75 years ago and [MCMastery on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3830983/mcmastery) was created 1.25 years ago. This is also apparently *somewhat* rectified as the MC account was last active 15 hours ago.