# I got an error when I tried to login to my account

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, google-openid

Enter email id in login box and press login button, without entering the password.

> [image: Enter email id in login box and press login button, without entering the password.]

Then click on g+ login you will get an error that 'The password is incorrect. Which is a bug, it should redirect to g+ login screen'

> [image: Then click on g+ login you will get an error that 'The password is incorrect. Which is a bug, it should redirect to g+ login screen']

Comment: You are supposed to enter password, right??

Comment: You need to click "Google" first and login via Google. Those text boxes are only for Stack Exchange OpenID, which you probably don't have.

Comment: You forgot to hide your email address in the second screenshot. lol

Answer (score 2):

There was a back-end test that assumed that if an email was filled in, this was not an attempt to use an openId/OAuth provider.

I removed that test - this will be with you in the next build (meta rev 2015.11.20.3900, rev 2015.11.20.3007).

Answer (score 1):

This is a combination of a user error and a bug to me.

If you want to log in using Google, you need to click the Google button *before you do something else*. The login form you see is to log in with your Stack Exchange Open ID, not with Google. (There is already [a feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263470/245360) to make this more obvious)

What I find odd, is that if you start to fill in something, and click the Google button, it doesn't redirect you to Google but instead tries to log you on. That confuses me since the Google button shouldn't do that. I think that is a bug and should be fixed.

Comment: Huh! So weird..

Comment: Indeed. OP burried the context in the image alt's. That's why it wasn't that obvious what he meant.